# Find the equation of the line segment

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, 3d

I'm currently studying Analytic Geometry in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and I'm stuck in this exercise:

Find the equation of the line that passes through the point
$A\left(\, 1,1,1\, \right)$, that is also parallel to the plane
$\pi = x - y + z - 3 = 0$ and intersects the lines $x = 1$ and $y = 3$.

I know that the equation of the line I need to find needs to be perpendicular to the normal vector of the plane, however I'm lost on how I'd also make the line equation intersect those lines $x =1$ and $y = 3$.

Comment: Is it really two separate line segments, or the single line segment where $x=1$ intersects $y=3$?  You say "segment" in the question.

Comment: @Carser whoops my bad, yeah two separate line segments i guess, as the line segment i need to find needs to be parallel to the plane, pass through that point and that also intersects those two line segments, is what I understand from the exercise's approach

Comment: In 3D though, $x=1$ and $y=3$ are both planes.  However, there is a line where they intersect that is "up" and "down" in the $z$ direction.

Comment: You say "line segment" but $x = 1$ and $y = 3$ are _lines_ not _line segments_....actually planes in $3$D space.

Comment: @Jared sorry i've just changed that! my bad, i'm not used to mathematical terms in english i know those lines are planes in 3d space however, i need to find the line equation that suffices those conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal vector to your plane is $\langle 1, -1, 1\rangle$.  As **Carser** pointed out, the planes $x = 1$ and $y = 3$ intersect on a line which has the form $\langle 1, 3, z \rangle$.  The slope of your line segment will thus be:

\begin{align}
\vec{A} - \langle 1, 3, z \rangle =&\ \langle1 - 1, 1 - 3, 1 - z \rangle \\
=&\ \langle 0, -2, 1 - z \rangle
\end{align}

This should be perpendicular to the normal vector of the plane thus:

$$
\langle 1, -1, 1\rangle \circ \langle 0, -2, 1 - z \rangle = 0
$$

This gives:

$$
0 + 2 + 1 - z = 0 \rightarrow 3-z = 0 \rightarrow z = 3
$$

Therefore your line passes through the line segment from $\langle 1,1,1\rangle$ to $\langle 1, 3, 3 \rangle$.